# Does media player stop automatically when the media stops playing?

Tags: c++, qt, media-player

I am creating a media player and playing a saved mp3 file like this:

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/path"));
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

Does MediaPlayer stops itself after playing the mp3 or I need to stop it manually after a specified time?

Comment: You can find out that yourself. Just connect a slot to [`QMediaPlayer::stateChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#stateChanged) signal and check if the state changes to `QMediaPlayer::StoppedState` once the media file ends.

Comment: Would you care to respond?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does stop automatically.

Indeed the documentations does not mention that explicitly. However, by connecting to the [`QMediaPlayer::stateChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#stateChanged) signal, like this:

```
connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::stateChanged, [](QMediaPlayer::State newState){
    qDebug() << newState;
});
```

when the song ends, the following message is logged in the console:

> QMediaPlayer::StoppedState

Note: I have had to listen to a whole song of Tina Turner to make this experiment. I am not saying it is bad, but just mentioning the fact.